# Outlook HTML email margin spacing

Tags: html, email, outlook

We have a wysisyg editor where the users writes their email content and clicks send, so we need the HTML to be as clean as possible. E.g:

```
<p><a href="">Nam velit metus</a>, vulputate eget sodales ut, dignissim vehicula nisi. Lorem ipsum@dolor.com sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Nunc pharetra luctus mi, sollicitudin ultrices lacus iaculis sed. Nam aliquam, tortor id sodales scelerisque.</p>
```

The problem is that Outlook has dropped support for margin/padding so the only way round this would be to create the content as :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: left; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;  line-height: 18px;"><a href="">Nam velit metus</a>, vulputate eget sodales ut, dignissim vehicula nisi. Lorem ipsum@dolor.com sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: left; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;  line-height: 18px;">Nunc pharetra luctus mi, sollicitudin ultrices lacus iaculis sed. Nam aliquam, tortor id sodales scelerisque.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So my question is am I better off trying to;

1. Edit the wysisyg so that it produces tables instead of paragraphs by
   default. First look at this its going to be next to impossible.
2. Or another idea would be to automatically edit the HTML source before send, maybe checking for 2 paragraphs and inserting a spaces table in between e.g

   ```
    <p><a href="">Nam velit metus</a>, vulputate eget sodales ut, dignissim vehicula nisi. Lorem ipsum@dolor.com sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

    <!--[if mso]>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
    <![endif]-->

    <p>Nunc pharetra luctus mi, sollicitudin ultrices lacus iaculis sed. Nam aliquam, tortor id sodales scelerisque.</p>
   ```

I probably prefer this method so next question would be am I best applying this fix to outlook only as shown above or apply this to all adding `<p style="margin:0; padding:0;">`.

Comment: Thanks @PA I was having a nightmere trying to the the code block to format correctly.

Comment: can't you just add some styling? `<style>p {margin:0}</style>`?

Comment: Nope everything needs to be inline, gmail strips all code blocks like this.

Comment: I believe Outlook is the only client with `<p>` tag issues, so targeting in the head should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For html email, everything should be in tables. That being said, you can insert your wysiwyg'ed content into a pre-existing `<td>` and you should be good to go.

At least one major email service provider I know use `<p>` tags in their wysiwyg. Try adding this to your `<style>` tag:

`#outlook a {padding:0;}`

Personally I don't like `<p>` tags in html. That style code above may fix the problems, but I haven't bothered to check, as I find double `<br>` to be easier/quicker anyway.

Here are 3 common techniques for vertical spacing:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td>

&nbsp;<br>      <!-- Some clients will collapse empty rows, so &nbsp; is needed -->
Content here
<br><br>
More content here
<br>&nbsp;


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

OR

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">

Content here
<br><br>
More content here

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

OR

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td height="20">&nbsp;   <!-- Some clients will collapse empty rows, so &nbsp; is needed -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

Content here
<br><br>
More content here

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```